# How to return tree's leaves in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tree, binary-tree

I have this code so far:

```
data BinaryTree a  = Null | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)

treeLeaves :: BinaryTree a -> [a]
treeLeaves tree = case tree of
    Null         -> []
    Node v t1 t2 -> [] ++ treeLeaves t1 ++ treeLeaves t2
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. It outputs an empty list.

Comment: Before writing it in Haskell, please first explain how you would do it yourself? What steps do you want the program to take to return the leaves?

Comment: `[] ++ x ++ y` is `x ++ y`. At what point will `treeLeaves` return something else than `[]`?

Comment: The `v` argument from `Node v t1 t2` isn't used in the implementation. Hm, maybe we can either do something with it or use `_` instead not to be distracted...

Answer (score 5):

Right now you are missing the important step, which is adding the leaves to your list, and that's why you are always getting an empty list. This `[] ++ treeLeaves t1 ++ treeLeaves t2` will eventually fall in the `Null` branch and become `[] ++ [] ++ ... ++ []` as Zeta commented.

You know you have reached a leaf when the `BinaryTree` is `Node v Null Null`. So you need to write a branch for that case too:

```
treeLeaves :: BinaryTree a -> [a]
treeLeaves tree = case tree of
    Null             -> []
    Node v Null Null -> v:[]
    Node _ t1 t2     -> treeLeaves t1 ++ treeLeaves t2
```

As Igor commented you can use `_` instead of `v` on the last line because you are not using the element in that node (since it isn't a leaf).